# Simple item and inventory system

Tags: c#, beginner, game

Items.cs, Creates dictionaries, enumerators, and classes for every type of item.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Item {
    // Medical
    public static Dictionary < Medical, ItemMedical > Medicals = new Dictionary<Medical, ItemMedical>() {
    { Medical.bandage, new ItemMedical() { name = "bandage", healing = 15, weight = 0.2f, value = 75, description =
        "Simple bandage to dress minor injuries. For patching up boo boos when you fall off your bicycle, won't save you from a gunshot." }},
    { Medical.tourniquet, new ItemMedical() { name = "tourniquet", healing = 25, weight = 0.7f, value = 225, description =
        "A device that tightly wraps around a limb near the wound to stop the flow of blood, more importantly, it stops blood from flowing OUT." }}
    };
    // Weapon
    public static Dictionary < Weapon, ItemWeapon > Weapons = new Dictionary < Weapon, ItemWeapon > () {
    { Weapon.shortsword, new ItemWeapon() { name = "shortsword", Damage = 25, weight = 4, value = 750, description =
        "A relatively short sword, hence the very creative name \"Shortsword\"." }}, 
    { Weapon.longsword, new ItemWeapon() { name = "longsword", Damage = 40, weight = 6, value = 950, description = 
        "A relatively long sword, hence the very creative name \"Longsword\"." }}
    };
    // Armor
    public static Dictionary < Armor, ItemArmor > Armors = new Dictionary < Armor, ItemArmor > () {
    { Armor.police_vest, new ItemArmor() { name = "police vest", Resistance = 25, Durability = 15, weight = 5, value = 1200, description =
        "A pistol grade body armor used by police forces." }},
    { Armor.military_vest, new ItemArmor() { name = "military vest", Resistance = 60, Durability = 40, weight = 8, value = 2400, description =
        "A heavy military vest capable of withstanding some rifle rounds." }}
    };
  public static ItemMedical Get(Medical key) => Medicals[key];
  public static ItemWeapon Get(Weapon key) => Weapons[key];
  public static ItemArmor Get(Armor key) => Armors[key];
}
public enum Medical {
  bandage,
  tourniquet
}
public enum Weapon {
  shortsword,
  longsword
}
public enum Armor {
  police_vest,
  military_vest
}

public class ItemMedical: ItemBase {
  public float healing = 0;
}

public class ItemWeapon: ItemBase {
  private float damage = 0;
  public float Damage {
    get => damage;
    set => damage = value;
  }
}

public class ItemArmor: ItemBase {
  // Damage required to penetrate armor
  public float Resistance = 0;
  // "health" of the armor, damaged much more if penetrated
  private float durability = 0;
  public float Durability {
    get => durability;
    set => durability = Math.Clamp(value, 0, value);
  }
}

public class ItemBase {
  public string name = "No name";
  public string description = "No description";
  public float weight = 0;
  public float value = 0;
}
```

Inventory.cs, equipment is an array because the slots never change, but backpack is a list because i dont know how many items will be in there.

```
  public static ItemBase[] equipment = new ItemBase[4] {
    // Primary weapon
    Item.Get(Weapon.longsword),
    // Secondary weapon
    Item.Get(Weapon.shortsword),
    // Body armor
    Item.Get(Armor.police_vest),
    // Rig
    null
  };
  public static List<ItemBase> backpack = new List<ItemBase>() {
      Item.Get(Medical.bandage),
      Item.Get(Medical.bandage),
  };
}
```

Usage

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Console.WriteLine("Items in inventory:");
    foreach(ItemBase item in Inventory.equipment) {
      if (item != null) Console.WriteLine(item.name);
      else Console.WriteLine("Nothing");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\nItems in backpack:");
    foreach(ItemBase item in Inventory.backpack) {
      Console.WriteLine(item.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

`Items in inventory:`
`longsword`
`shortsword`
`police vest`
`Nothing`

`Items in backpack:`
`bandage`
`bandage`

My first actually competant looking piece of code as a beginner. Really proud of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, congratulation it is a great first attempt. Even though it does not contain too much functionality rather structure and data.

Most of my recommendation will be related to C# coding conventions. Some of my suggestions are taking advantage of C# 9's new features so I'll share some links about them.

#### Enums

```
public enum Medical { Bandage, Tourniquet }
public enum Weapon { ShortSword, LongSword }
public enum Armor { PoliceVest, MilitaryVest }
```

- In C# we usually use PascalCasing for enum members

  - In your `Weapon` enum you have used lower casing
  - whereas in your `Armor` enum you have used snake_casing
  - Please try to chase consistency across your domain model
- Most of the time when the enum contains less than 5 members (and they are not overwriting default values) C# developers tend to define the enum in a single line

#### Base class

```
public abstract class ItemBase
{
    public string Name { get; init; } = "No name";
    public string Description { get; init; } = "No description";
    public float Weight { get; init; }
    public float Value { get; init; }
}
```

- This class is used to define common properties that's why it is advisable to mark it as `abstract`

  - That prevents the consumer of this class to instantiate an object from it
  - You want to allow to be able to create only derived classes
- C# developers are preferring properties over fields whenever they are public

  - That's why I've changed all the base class members to properties
  - I've also changed their name since in C# we normally use Pascal Casing for properties
  - I've used [`init`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init) instead of `set`, because it only allows initialization (via constructor or via object initializer)

    - So, after an item is created with a specified values it can't be changed later on
  - Since C# 6 you can define [default value for auto generated fields](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties)

#### Derived classes

```
public class ItemMedical : ItemBase
{
    public float Healing { get; init; }
}

public class ItemWeapon : ItemBase
{
    public float Damage { get; init; }
}

public class ItemArmor : ItemBase
{
    public float Resistance { get; init; }
    private float durability;
    public float Durability
    {
        get => durability;
        set => durability = Math.Clamp(value, 0, value);
    }
}
```

- Please prefer auto-generated properties over manually creating backing fields and defining getter and setter methods

  - The only exception is whenever you have custom logic either inside the getter or inside the setter (like `Durability`)
- I've get rid of the `= 0` initial value assignments since these are their [default values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)

#### The Item class #1

This *constant data* class can be implemented in several ways. One way to achieve it as you have done it.

- In this case you can mark the class itself as `static` since all of its member is `static` as well
- If you expose the dictionaries (`public`) then you should consider to make them [immutable](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?view=net-5.0) to prevent further element removal or addition after intialization

```
public static class Item
{
    public static readonly ImmutableDictionary<Medical, ItemMedical> Medicals = new Dictionary<Medical, ItemMedical>
    {
        {
            Medical.Bandage,
            new()
            {
                Name = "bandage",
                Healing = 15,
                Weight = 0.2f,
                Value = 75,
                Description = "Simple bandage to dress minor injuries. For patching up boo boos when you fall off your bicycle, won't save you from a gunshot."
            }
        },
        {
            Medical.Tourniquet,
            new()
            {
                Name = "tourniquet",
                Healing = 25,
                Weight = 0.7f,
                Value = 225,
                Description = "A device that tightly wraps around a limb near the wound to stop the flow of blood, more importantly, it stops blood from flowing OUT."
            }
        }
    }.ToImmutableDictionary();

    ...

    public static ItemMedical Get(Medical key) => Medicals[key];
    public static ItemWeapon Get(Weapon key) => Weapons[key];
    public static ItemArmor Get(Armor key) => Armors[key];
}
```

- I've marked the collections as `readonly` to prevent overwriting with another collection or null by the consumer of the class
- I've used `new()` ([target typed new expression](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new)) to avoid repeating the class names over and over again

  - It can be inferred from the Dictionary type parameter

#### The Item class #2

Let me show you an alternative approach:

```
public class Item
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Item> singleton = new Lazy<Item>(new Item());
    public static Item Instance => singleton.Value;

    private Item() { }

    private readonly Dictionary<Medical, ItemMedical> Medicals = new ()
    {
        {
            Medical.Bandage,
            new ()
            {
                Name = "bandage",
                Healing = 15,
                Weight = 0.2f,
                Value = 75,
                Description = "Simple bandage to dress minor injuries. For patching up boo boos when you fall off your bicycle, won't save you from a gunshot."
            }
        },
        {
            Medical.Tourniquet,
            new ()
            {
                Name = "tourniquet",
                Healing = 25,
                Weight = 0.7f,
                Value = 225,
                Description = "A device that tightly wraps around a limb near the wound to stop the flow of blood, more importantly, it stops blood from flowing OUT."
            }
        }
    };

    ...

    public ItemMedical this[Medical key] => Medicals[key];
    public ItemWeapon this[Weapon key] => Weapons[key];
    public ItemArmor this[Armor key] => Armors[key];
}
```

- Here I've made the dictionaries `private` so they became **implementation details**
- I've replaced the `Get` methods to [index operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/using-indexers) to make the item retrieval a bit more convenient

  - See next section for usage
  - The index operators can't be defined as `static` so we have to make a little trick here to make the usage easy
- We use the [singleton pattern](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton#lazy) to expose a single instance to the consumers of the class

  - Here I've implemented this pattern with a [`Lazy`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0) to make sure that the instance is created only when it is first accessed but in a thread safe manner

These changes allow us to define the `Equipments` and `Backpack` like this:

```
public ItemBase[] Equipments = new []
{
    Item.Instance[Weapon.LongSword],
    Item.Instance[Weapon.ShortSword],
    Item.Instance[Armor.PoliceVest],
    (ItemBase)null
};

public List<ItemBase> Backpack = new ()
{
    Item.Instance[Medical.Bandage],
    Item.Instance[Medical.Bandage],
};
```